# Android WebView Push assign name to DeviceID

Tags: android, authentication, webview, push, personalization

I am developing an Android App with WebView and Push notifications.
The problem is, that the website i'm displaying has a login.

What I want to do is:
If somebody logs into the website via my App (WebView!), I need to take the username he entered and put it into my MySQL-Database with the Android-Device-ID. (but just, if his password was correct..)

Does anybody know of an elegant way to do this? I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I put an alertdialog over the websites original Login.
After this, I injected Java Script Code into the URL, which fills out the forms on the website and then automatically submits.
If anybody is interested, I did it like this:

AlertDialog for the **logIn**:

```
    private void logIn() {
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.activity_login, null);
        final EditText username = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        final EditText password = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.password);
        username.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        password.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>Login</font>"));
        alert.setView(textEntryView);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Login",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        User = username.getText().toString();
                        Pw = password.getText().toString();
                        autoFillIn();
                    }
                });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {
                    }
                });
        alert.show();
}
```

And then **autoFillIn**:

```
    public void autoFillIn(){
        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('LoginForm_username').value = '" + User + "';document.getElementById('LoginForm_password').value='" + Pw + "';document.forms[0].submit();");
        }
    });
    mWebview .loadUrl(frontendurl);
    setContentView(mWebview);

}
```

Hope this might help somebody.
And i'm always open for better ideas..

Edit:
"frontendurl" is a string with the url i want to display via webview..